# Как сохранять ответ от пользователя в TXT

Tags: python, aiogram

В python недавно,нужно чтобы после решения капчи она сохранялась в txt файл,пытался но ничего не получилось,бот отправляет капчу,а после моего ответа выходит ошибка AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'content_type'

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    message=open("C:\\Users\1121\\Desktop\\123123\\captcha.txt", "w")
    await message.content_type(message.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

у вас указано `message: types.Message` а потом `message=open("C:\\Users\1121\\Desktop\\123123\\captcha.txt", "w")` (open не имеет атрибута  'content_type')  переименуйте вторую переменую на другое название, например `captcha`

```
captcha=open("C:\\Users\1121\\Desktop\\123123\\captcha.txt", "w")
```

Answer (score 0):

Капчу нужно сохранить в переменную какую то, а после чего записать уже в тхт и желательно не через open, а через with open

```
    with open("C:\\Users\1121\\Desktop\\123123\\captcha.txt", "w") as 
    file:
        file.write(captcha)
```